# Iterating over a map that has values of list type

Tags: java, hashmap

I have the below method to fetch order id for a particular store

```java
Map<String, List<String>> extractOrderId (String StoreId) {
    // business logic
}
```

Now I have to execute the above method for all the store id's , so  i have done it as shown below but i want to store all the results in a different `HashMap` named as `resultFinalMap`

```java
Map<String, List<String>> resultFinalMap;    
for (String store: StoreIdList) {    
    // Storing all the store id as key and
    // corresponding value of order ids in the list mapped against the key    

}
```

So `resultFinalMap` would contain key as all the different store id and the values would be different orders that are fetched against the store id.

Comment: Your question is not really clear. First method doesn't fetch orderID, as it returns composite Map. Also, it's not really well articulated what you want to do in the second method. Could you please edit your question?

Comment: Is the key of the map returned by `extractOrderId` indicate storeId?

Comment: @GauthamM yes you are correct

Comment: This the question is not clear, it would be better if you put some sample input and expected output map

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri I have done the same

Comment: @asderfgh your first method doesn't return String storeId. Again: It returns Map.

Comment: Which is the `storeId` in `Map<String, List<String>>`?

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri I am trying to create a new map in which i will store the result of all store id as the key and value as the order id

Comment: So, you want `Map<String, String>` to have a storId as a key, and orderId as a value? but your final map is `Map<String, List<String>> resultFinalMap`...

Comment: Also, what is `StoreIdList`? I'm voting to close this question as it's really unclear. Please edit it and provide clearer question.

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a POJO that will store

```
class Order {
   String orderId;
   //rest of your order class
}

class Store {
    
    String storeId;
    //This will store your orders by id
 
    Map<String, Order> orders;
    
    public Order getOrder(String orderId) {
        return orders.get(orderId);
    }
}
```

Comment: ..and how this will help? or what this will help?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have mentioned that the key of the map returned by `extractOrderId` indicates `storeId` itself, then I assume that the map returned would have a single key. then it would be better to return a `List` instead of the `Map` in `extractOrderId`

```java
List<String> extractOrderId (String StoreId){
    // business logic
}
```

```java
Map<String, List<String>> resultFinalMap = new HashMap<>(); 
for (String store: StoreIdList) {
    resultFinalMap.put(store, extractOrderId(store));
}
```